# HTML Email CSS Not Rendering Properly in Outlook

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to generate an html email being sent to customers. It renders find in most email clients but I am experiencing issues in Outlook Express and Outlook. Basically, I am trying to reserve two lines of space for my product link (two lines to be shown even if there is only one line of text). This works fine is other clients but not in these. Additionally, in outlook express the hyperlinks are always dark blue with a text underline. How can I standardize the size of the grid boxes along with fixing the hyperlink color. The color issue only happens in outlook express. The missing images are to remove logos from the posted image, this is not an issue.

[image]

```
<table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:600px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="290" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0"
                cellpadding="0" style="width:290px;background-color:#403E3E;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="290" style="width:290px;"><a href=
                            "javascript:parent.onLocalLink('147d2e8a9b6c608e_',window.frameElement)">
                            <img src=
                            "https://img.examplecom/deal/usifhj6vPAYwqyziASU3bQ/la_giralda_guanaja 960x582/v1/t440x300.jpg"
                            border="1" width="290" height="180" style=
                            "border-width: 0px;" /></a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"
                                cellpadding="7" style="width:100%;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" style=
                                            "text-align:justify;"><font face=
                                            "Myriad Pro,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
                                            size="1" color="white"><span style=
                                            "font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;"><img src="http://www.example.com/logo.png"
                                            alt="company" style=
                                            "border-width: 0px;" /></span></font></td>

                                            <td align="right" style=""><font face=
                                            "Myriad Pro,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
                                            size="1" color="white"><span style=
                                            "font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;">$525</span></font></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"
                                            style="height:30px;text-align:justify;">
                                            <font face=
                                            "Myriad Pro,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
                                            size="1" color="white"><span style=
                                            "font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;"><a href="redir.aspx?C=Jezygmq7Nku0dS69lHHft1DXFwYci9EI6vwB1g6JI-sjWTq81HrEm2dti2OozSQmHVUiyLo1Br0.&amp;URL=http%3a%2f%2f-featured_url-"
                                            target="_blank">Name of the product being
                                            sold</a></span></font></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"
                                            style="height:30px;text-align:justify;">
                                            <font face=
                                            "Myriad Pro,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
                                            size="1" color="white"><span style=
                                            "font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;">Other
                                            info</span></font></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style=
                            "width:100%;height:15px;background-color:white;">
                            <span style="background-color:white;">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table width="290" align="right" border="0" cellspacing="0"
                cellpadding="0" style="width:290px;background-color:#403E3E;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="290" style="width:290px;"><a href=
                            "javascript:parent.onLocalLink('147d2e8a9b6c608e_',window.frameElement)">
                            <img src=
                            "https://img.example.com/deal/k44bFhz77oXnzEEcyTBW/y9-960x582/v1/t440x300.jpg"
                            border="1" width="290" height="180" style=
                            "border-width: 0px;" /></a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"
                                cellpadding="7" style="width:100%;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" style=
                                            "text-align:justify;"><font face=
                                            "Myriad Pro,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
                                            size="1" color="white"><span style=
                                            "font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;"><img src="http://www.example.com/logo.png"
                                            alt="Logo" style=
                                            "border-width: 0px;" /></span></font></td>

                                            <td align="right" style=""><font face=
                                            "Myriad Pro,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
                                            size="1" color="white"><span style=
                                            "font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;">$1355</span></font></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"
                                            style="height:30px;text-align:justify;">
                                            <font face=
                                            "Myriad Pro,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
                                            size="1" color="white"><span style=
                                            "font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;"><a href="redir.aspx?C=Jezygmq7Nku0dS69lHHft1DXFwYci9EI6vwB1g6JI-sjWTq81HrEm2dti2OozSQmHVUiyLo1Br0.&amp;URL=http%3a%2f%2f-featured_url-"
                                            target="_blank">This is an example
                                            product description for an item being
                                            sold</a></span></font></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"
                                            style="height:30px;text-align:justify;">
                                            <font face=
                                            "Myriad Pro,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
                                            size="1" color="white"><span style=
                                            "font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;">Other
                                            info</span></font></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style=
                            "width:100%;height:15px;background-color:white;">
                            <span style="background-color:white;">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The code used to generate these boxes are:

```
        $html = '<table align="'.$side.'" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="BoxWrap" style="background-color: #403e3e" width="290">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td border="0" class="RespoImage_TwoThirdsW" width="290"><a href="#" style="border: none;"><img alt="" border="0" class="RespoImage_TwoThirds" height="180" src="'.$params['image'].'" style="width: 290px; height: 180px; display: block;" width="290" alt="'.$params['title'].'" /></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td border="0" bgcolor="#403e3e" style="background-color: #403e3e; font-family: Myriad Pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 18px; text-align: left;"><img height="15" src="'.$this->siteurl.$params['provider']['logo'].'" style="height:15px;" alt="'.$params['provider']['provider_display'].'"></td>
                                            <td border="0" bgcolor="#403e3e" style="background-color: #403e3e; font-family: Myriad Pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 15px; text-align: right;"><span>'.$params['price'].'</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="justify" border="0" height="30" valign="top" bgcolor="#403e3e" colspan="2" style="overflow: hidden; vertical-align:top; height:30px; background-color: #403e3e; font-family: Myriad Pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 15px; text-align: left;">
                                                    <a href="-featured_url-" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px;">'.$params['title'].'</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td border="0" height="30" valign="top" bgcolor="#403e3e" colspan="2" style="vertical-align:top; height:30px; background-color: #403e3e; font-family: Myriad Pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 15px; text-align: left;">'.$this->create_location($params['location']['mapped_address']['address']['city'],$params['location']['mapped_address']['address']['state'],$params['location']['mapped_address']['address']['country']).'</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="RespoShowMedium" height="15" style="display:none;" width="100%">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give the exact row of the project description changes.

Instead of this

```
  <tr>
     <td align="justify" border="0" height="30" valign="top" bgcolor="#403e3e" colspan="2" style="overflow: hidden; vertical-align:top; height:30px; background-color: #403e3e; font-family: Myriad Pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 15px; text-align: left;">
      <a href="-featured_url-" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px;">'.$params['title'].'</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

Use like this

```
  <tr>
       <td align="justify" border="0" height="60" valign="top" bgcolor="#403e3e" colspan="2" style="overflow: hidden; vertical-align:top; background-color: #403e3e; font-family: Myriad Pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 15px; text-align: left;">
         <a href="-featured_url-" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px;"><span style="color:#fff;">'.$params['title'].'</span></a>
       </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Those changes don't seem to help as outlook automatically adjusts the html. I have adjusted my post to show the code actually sent to the email.

Comment: Ok. I have update my answer with your new code. check it out.

Comment: Hey, the adjustment of the height worked. I had to fine tune the number, but it seems consistent on the clients tested so far. However, the color of the link is still being forced to the blue.

Comment: I just checked, and while the height is now consistent in Outlook Express and Outlook.com, but not on AOL.com